# Java integer to byte array to short

Tags: java

I am trying to convert an Integer to a byte array (array of 4 bytes) and then I will extract the last 4 bits of each byte, then I will create a short from those last 4 digits of each bytes.

I have the following code but it always prints zero.

```
    private static short extractShort(byte[] byteArray) {
        short s = 1;
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
        for(int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
            byte lastFourBytes = extractLast4Bits(byteArray[i]);
            // Uses a bit mask to extract the bits we are interested in
            byteBuffer.put(lastFourBytes);
        }
       return  ByteBuffer.wrap(byteBuffer.array()).getShort();
    }


    private static byte extractLast4Bits(byte byteParam) {
        return  (byte) ( byteParam & 0b00001111);
    }

    private static byte[] intToByteArray(int i) {
        return new byte[] {
            (byte)((i >> 24) & 0xff),
            (byte)((i >> 16) & 0xff),
            (byte)((i >> 8) & 0xff),
            (byte)((i >> 0) & 0xff),
         };
    }

}
```

Any help will be sincerely appreciated

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just manipulate the integer and cast it to a short?

Comment: You should shift input to right on each iteration of the loop

Comment: Jannik I am learning by building, casting covers up the magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get the byte array, try this..

```java
    short val = 0;
    for (byte b : bytes) {
       val <<= 4;
       val |= (b&0xf)
    }
```

If you want to do it starting from an `int`, you can do it like this.

```java
      int v = 0b1110_1010_1111_1001_1010_1000_1010_0111;
      short verify = (short) 0b1010_1001_1000_0111;
      // initialize a short value
      short val = 0;

      // increment from 24 to 0 by 8's  the loop will
      // repeat 4 times.
      for (int i = 24; i >= 0; i -= 8) {
         // start by shifting the result left 4 bits
         // first time thru this does nothing.
         val <<= 4;

         // Shift the integer right by i bits (first time is
         // 24, next time is 16, etc
         // then mask off the lower order 4 bits of the right
         // most byte and OR it to the result(val).
         // then when the loop continues, val will be
         // shifted left 4 bits to allow for the next "nibble"

         val |= ((v >> i) & 0xf);
      }
      System.out.println(val);
      System.out.println(verify);
```

For more information on bitwise operators, check out this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) link.

Comment: Could you please explain what's going on in the for loop ? It works very well.

Comment: I added some comments.  If you have more questions let me know.  I presume you know and & and | work with bit manipulation.

Comment: Yes thank you very much. How do I accept this answer ?

Comment: @EdwardBanfa To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.  For more detailed information about managing answers on your question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers